# C# Get string between 2 HTML-tags

Tags: c#

I know this has been posted before, but I couldn't get it work.

I have this string: `<div class="s20 red">120.000.000 kr.</div>`

But I only want `120.000.000 kr.`

How can I isolate the string?

Comment: If your html is more complext than this then use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Regex:

```
 var a = @"<div class=""s20 red"">120.000.000 kr.</div>";
 var b = Regex.Match(a, "(?<=>)(.*)(?=<)");
 Console.WriteLine(b.Value);
```

Output: 
120.000.000 kr.

Comment: Regexes are excellent for this kind of pattern matching.

Comment: I just thought of something: What if there were multiple HTML tags in my string? How can I then only get 120.000.000 kr.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IndexOf` method to find where tags end and start, and the `SubString` method to get the text between them. Example:

```
string price = "<div class=\"s20 red\">120.000.000 kr.</div>";

int start = price.IndexOf('>');
int end = price.IndexOf('<', start);
price = price.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler alternative than all the text based solutions if your html is valid xml (minus header) which is the case in your snippet is to use the LINQ xml api

```
XElement.Parse(yourstring);
XElement.Value // this contains exactly what you asked for.
```