# How to get a string between 2 string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
<div class="fsxl fwb">Myname<br />
```

So how to get string Myname ?

here is my code:

```
public string name(string link)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(link);


        var output = htmlCode.Split("<div class="fsxl fwb">","<br />");

        return output.ToString();
    }
```

But the problem is `"<div class="fsxl fwb">"` it will become 2 string `"<div class=", ">" and fsxl fwb`  so how to fix it ?

Comment: You could have a look at a HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is the code really unescaped or is that a typo?

Comment: Don´t parse Html manually, use an existiong parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by parsing the HTML, that is often the best option.

A quick solution would be to use regex to get the string out. This one will do:

```
<div class="fsxl fwb">(.*?)<br \/>
```

It will capture the input between the `div` and the first following `<br />`.

This will be the C# code to get the answer:

```
string s = Regex.Replace
           ( "(.*)<div class=\"fsxl fwb\">Myname<br />"
           , "<div class=\"fsxl fwb\">(.*?)<br \\/>(.*)"
           , "$2"
           );
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: :o http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Oliver That was my first thought too! :)

Comment: That is not a very specific answer to this question @Oliver

Comment: @PatrickHofman I couldn't resist!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix to your code:

```
var output = htmlCode.Split(
    new [] { "<div class=\"fsxl fwb\">", "<br />"},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

return output[0];
```

It escapes the quotes correctly and uses a valid [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the Split method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = @"<div class='fsxl fwb'>Myname<br />";
var b = Regex.Match(a, "(?<=>)(.*)(?=<)");
Console.WriteLine(b.Value);
```

Code based on: [C# Get string between 2 HTML-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592120/c-sharp-get-string-between-2-html-tags)

Comment: :o http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You have changed the actual HTML to make it compiling in C#? How would that every match do you think?

Comment: If you identified the question as a duplicate you shouldn't duplicate an answer. I can understand that due to your low rep you cannot act by commenting or casting a close-as-duplicate vote.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
public string name(string link)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(link);


        Regex regex = new Regex("<div class=\"fsxl fwb\">(.*)<br />");
        Match match = regex.Match(htmlCode);
        string output = match.Groups[1].ToString();

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid regex, you can use this extension method to grab the text between two other strings:

```
public static string ExtractBetween(this string str, string startTag, string endTag, bool inclusive)
    {
        string rtn = null;
        var s = str.IndexOf(startTag);
        if (s >= 0)
        {
            if (!inclusive)
            {
                s += startTag.Length;
            }

            var e = str.IndexOf(endTag, s);
            if (e > s)
            {
                if (inclusive)
                {
                    e += startTag.Length +1;
                }
                rtn = str.Substring(s, e - s);
            }
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```

Example usage (note you need to add the escape characters to your string)

```
var s = "<div class=\"fsxl fwb\">Myname<br />";
var r = s.ExtractBetween("<div class=\"fsxl fwb\">", "<br />", false);
Console.WriteLine(r);
```